# Measure Theory Counterpart of Slutsky and Continuous Mapping Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

As the title says I am looking for the measure theory counterparts of slutsky and continuous mapping theorem. So far I only found both theorems in probability theorey related literature (even for literature that focuses mainly on measure theory). So I wonder, a) are there counterparts at all and if yes b) what additional assumption do they require?

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting question indeed. 
Perhaps [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-01/S0002-9939-1961-0120342-2/S0002-9939-1961-0120342-2.pdf) gives a counterpart of sorts for the continuous mapping theorem. It says that convergence almost everywhere is preserved under a continuous mapping (Theorem 1), while convergence in measure is preserved under a uniformly continous mapping (Theorem 2). I am not sure how we would go about convergence in distribution as it is a probabilistic term.

Comment: Thanks for the article. 

There exists the concepts of convergence of measures in measure theory (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures) which is the counterpart to convergence in distribution.